# Can I add a context menu entry to audio files in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I'd like to be able to right-click on various audio file types, especially flac, wav, and mp3 files, and run an old version 10 of dbPowerAMP Music Converter (which IMO is superior to more recent versions).  Here's the address of the file I want to run:

Local Disk (C:)/Program Files (x86)/Illustrate/dBpowerAMP/MusicConverter.exe

I know there are other questions like this on superuser.com, but I don't understand the answers.  I *think* I'm supposed to use notepad to create a text file containing registry info, then rename it to something like dmc.reg, then double-click on it to (somehow) add it to the registry.  But the remaining details are unclear to me.

Any chance someone would be so kind as to hold my hand through this process?

Thanks!

P.S.  I thought perhaps I could simply do an "open with" command without messing with the registry.  But that only seems to work when I highlight a single file, whereas I need this to work with multiple files highlighted.

Comment: If you can link to the installer you used for that program, this will help as I can install it in W10 and try to solve the issue.

Comment: @Moab Sure, you can get it here:  https://www.krubow.com/Downloads/dMC-r10.exe

Comment: @Moab It's a pretty sweet program btw.  Much better than foobar2000 for encoding/decoding.  (Although I still have to use foobar2000 to do cuesplitting.)

Comment: I found it at oldversion.com, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

OK, I installed V10 on my Windows 10 64bit.

Once installed I checked the context menu and there was no entry for it, so I right clicked on a flac file and selected "open with" to get a selection menu, then selected "Choose another app" then selected "more apps" then scrolled to bottom and selected "look for another app on this pc".

This will open the wrong programs folder you need, keep this window open and navigate to "program files (x86), then open the illustrate folder and then open the dbPowerAmp folder, in here highlight "MusicConvertor.exe" and hit the open button to close the window.

The context menu entry should now show in the Open With menu.

If I figure out how to get the "convert to" menu item I will update this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  However, I had already tried this and it only works for single -file highlighting.  I'm attempting to make it so that I can do it with multiple files highlighted (for instance an entire album).

Comment: Ill work on that, its part of the "convert to" context menu item that is missing, give me some time,